IP Conflict and VPN-Based Overlay Network Setup over WAN / VPN Solutions for Sites with Overlapping IP Address Ranges
I want to ping from a computer located in SITE C to computers in SITE A and SITE B within the topology.
One of my biggest challenges here is determining how to establish an overlay network over the WAN.
Another challenge is that the network infrastructures in SITE A and SITE B share the same IP blocks, and I cannot change them.
For example, when I want to access the computer in SITE A and ping 192.168.1.100, the same IP exists in SITE B. How can I configure this network without causing any IP conflicts?
What VPN technologies can I use to overcome these problems?
                 SITE A                                    SITE B
                  [PC]                                     [PC]
            192.168.1.0/24                           192.168.1.0/24
                    |                                        |
                [Router]                                  [Router]
                    |                                        |
            192.168.2.0/24                           192.168.2.0/24
                    |                                        |
                [Router]                                  [Router]
                    |                                        |
             172.16.11.0/24                           172.12.12.0/24
                     \                                      /
                      \                                    /
                       \            [ WAN ]               /
                        \________________________________/
                                      |
                                  172.11.10.0/24
                                      |
                                  [Router C]
                                      |
                                 192.168.3.0/24
                                      |
                                     [PC]
                                    SITE C


VPN can use Network Address Translation to overcome that design problem.
Here is an example.

Thank you. I will review the page, but I am thinking about where to configure the VPN in this scenario. I do not have direct access from Site C to the networks (192.168.2.0 and 192.168.1.0) at Site A and B. I need to set up an overlay network, but I am stuck on how to proceed.

You configure the VPN on whatever device you have access to which will have the ability to host the VPN. The specifics depend on the equipment and actual networks involved. I see no need for any kind of overlay network if you just want to setup VPN connections. If you want to address overlay networks in general or the specifics of the actual equipment and networks in a real deployment, you need to make a new question with those details.
